# javascript cannot remove event listener onbeforeunload from list

Tags: javascript

I tried all possible ways to remove an event from `window` object :

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
window.BeforeUnloadEvent = null;
$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
$(window).off('onbeforeunload');
window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', carol, true);
window.removeEventListener('onbeforeunload', carol, true); // carol is that function see image below
```

and when i type getEventListener(window) is still present there

[image]

does anybody know another way or am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading `"on"` is only used when event listeners are accessed as object properties. When removing the event, just use the event name:

```
 window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', carol, true);
```

Comment: i cannot see this event with $._data(window, "events");  only with getEventListeners() API and cannot be used in scripts :(((

Comment: Why do you need to see it to remove it?

Comment: on a checkout page if some webservice fail from ajax . so i need to remove it somehow but keep it otherwise :(

Comment: That's application logic unrelated to this question. If the event removal works for you now, accept this answer and ask another question about making it conditional. If the callback still fails to remove update your question with more code, I don't see any other issues with the solution.